# FSharp getting error: error FS0192 the anonymous record <>f__AnonymousType has not been generated in the pre-phase of generating this module

Tags: .net-core, f#

I'm trying to use Anonymous Records for the first time but getting an error on compile:
error FS0192 the anonymous record <>f__AnonymousType has not been generated in the pre-phase of generating this module

I'm using visual studio code on xubuntu and I don't see any errors in the IDE - so at least ionide seems to accept it; I only get the error when trying to run

dotnet version= 2.1.603

The offending code:

```
let load<'a> connectionString schemaDef (selector:obj) =
    select<'a> connectionString schemaDef selector |> List.tryHead   


let validateToken (clientToken:ClientWebToken) = 
    let loadedToken = liteOrm.load<WebToken> connectionString WebToken.SchemaDef {| TokenGuid= clientToken.TokenGuid |}
    match loadedToken with
```

I can get around this by passing a typed record:

```
type TokenGuid = {
    TokenGuid: Guid
}

let validateToken (clientToken:ClientWebToken) = 
    let loadedToken = liteOrm.load<WebToken> connectionString WebToken.SchemaDef { TokenGuid= clientToken.TokenGuid }
    match loadedToken with
```

or by explicitly declaring the structure of the anonymous record (which I don't want to do):

```
let load<'a> connectionString schemaDef (selector: {| TokenGuid: Guid |}) =
    select<'a> connectionString schemaDef selector |> List.tryHead
```

The issue I believe is that the compiler is unable to infer an appropriate type or convert the anonymous record to an obj. 
Is there any way to pass the anonymous record as a generic object to a method and if so what type should the parameter be ?

Comment: Does adding either `inline` or changing `selector:obj` to `selector:^b` make a difference? The compiler *might* be able to resolve type at compile time with either of these, but I couldn't tell you off the top of my head.

Comment: @LSM07 - thanks a lot - I tried both options but still get the same compiler error. Does the ^b refer to a generic type or is it for something else?

Comment: `^T` as opposed to `'T` indicates a statically resolved type as opposed to a generic type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters .

Comment: thanks for the info - I did try as ^b with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/6434) for passing an anonymous record to something accepting `obj` as its input parameter. This will be fixed. In the meantime, I recommend specifying the type explicitly or using type inference rather than the `obj` parameter type.